# How much points for BS(Software Engineering) Degree Title for Quebec skilled worker program 2015?

Tags: canada, immigration

I am confused with title of my Bachelors Degree to calculate points for QSW 2015.
Title of my Degree is BS(Software Engineering) 4 Years.
Is this degree can be categorized in Bachelors in Computer Science or Bachelors in Computer Engineering ? Also please tell me how much points i can earn ?

Comment: "Software Engineering" is usually a degree equivalent to "Computer Science", in most cases the only difference is the department that runs the degree (math/sciences vs engineering). But you'll have to evaluate the actual coursework vs the QSW requirements to know for sure.

Comment: @littleadv i have emailed to Quebec Immigration department but they did not respond me back yet .

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a difference between Software Engineering and Computer Science in terms of the degree. The short answer is that engineering degrees are accredited by CEAB because engineering is regulated in Canada. The job market is about the same for all of them though.

In your case, I'd probably pick the Bachelor's in Computer Engineering option.

For more information see the differences between Computer Science, Computer Engineering and Software Engineering on the University of Waterloo website. Check these links out,

https://uwaterloo.ca/software-engineering/future-undergraduate-students/frequently-asked-questions#Difference

https://uwaterloo.ca/software-engineering/future-undergraduate-students/comparing-bse-bcs